# Preventing cross-site scripting in ASP.NET MVC pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, cross-site

During a security test the following was flagged as a problem.

Reflected Cross-Site Scripting in the "gridName" Parameter - Grid - Cross site scripting

```
../grid/index?pageName=griddetail&gridName=%22;alert(24);+%22
```

Is there a way to prevent this for the entire site. Maybe something in OnActionExecuting?

Comment: You will need to show the source line of the view where it uses the pageName variable.